# Can someone explain the concept of nontrivial joint sufficient statistic for a pair of parameters?

Tags: self-study, estimation, sufficient-statistics

How to find joint sufficient statistic for a pair of unknown parameters from a bivariate random sample? Also, what exactly does nontrivial mean in this context? Please elaborate and be simple in your illustration, as much as you can.

Comment: The question is too vague. What is the joint distribution of the two random variables? Are they independent or not? What are the two unknown parameters of interest? Are there any other parameters, and if yes, are they considered known or unknown?

Answer (score 1):

A statistic $T$ is *sufficient* for a parameter $\theta$ if and only if there exist a factorisation of the data $f(X;\theta) = h(X) g(T(X);\theta)$, where $f(\dot)$ is the respective density function or mass function.

Consider a sample coming from the Normal distribution $ X \overset{d}= N(\mu, \sigma)$. Here we have $\theta := (\mu, \sigma)$. See that the sufficient statistic $T_1 := X$, i.e. the sample itself, is sufficient for $\theta$, as we have $f(X;\theta)=1 \cdot g (X; \theta)$. This is a trivial sufficient statistic as I have not reduced the information in the sample. Now we are left to play around with $f(X;\theta)$. If you follow this [link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/285) and go through the first example, you will get your answer. The word 'joint' is coming from me not knowing $\mu$ nor knowing $\sigma$, thus having a sufficient statistic $T:=(T_\mu, T_\sigma)$ that is sufficient for $\theta = (\mu, \sigma)$ together.